# Why do people say 小学校の時 or 中学校の時?

Tags: particle-の, relative-clauses

When reffering to the school days, people often say `小学校の時`, `中学校の時`. Even though this may not be wrong, they are shortened forms of relatively complex (redundant) structures. Thus, they are close to the expressions:

> 私が通っていた学校が小学校だった時
>   'when the school that I used to attend was an elementary school'
>   私が通っていた学校が中学校だった時
>   'when the school that I used to attend was a junior high school'

I think that there is a much simpler way to express the same situation, such as:

> 私が小学生だった時
>   'when I was an elementary school student'
>   私が中学生だった時
>   'when I was a junior high school student'

which would be shortened to `小学生の時`, `中学生の時`, and I do hear people (including myself) using the latter. But still, many people seem to be using the former. Why do people use a more complicated way of saying it?

Comment: Because 小学校の時 is neither complicated nor redundant, unlike your “decompressed” expression.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Then, what is the meaning (role) of `小学校` in `小学校の時`?

Comment: I do not know, but how about interpreting 小学校の as 小学校に通っていた?  の simply converts a noun to a 連体修飾語 (modifier which modifies a noun; I do not know the English term for it), and its meaning can be almost anything.  It does not have to be replaceable to である.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto That is the underlying sentence, but I believe that `の` constructions like this one is related to a relative clause with a nominal predicate. So the the related relative clause should be in the form `...小学校だった`。In this case, that would be a cleft sentence.

Comment: I do not think that の-constructions like this must come from …である, but of course it depends on what we mean by “の-constructions like this.”

Comment: "modifier which modifies a noun" sounds like you are describing an adjective.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Modifier is a grammatical role, as opposed to argument and predicate. Adjective is a part of speech, as opposed to noun, verb, adverb, etc. They often correspond, but not necessarily. Especially, something that comes before `の` is a noun, not adjective.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I don't find it surprising. It may be just my own experience but,

English:

> [a] "When I was in (primary/secondary/middle/high/etc.) school......" (More common)
>
> as opposed to,
>
> [b] "When I was a (primary/secondary/middle/high/etc.) school student......" (Not as common)

Chinese:

> [a] "(我在)[小/中/大]学時......" (More common)
>
> as opposed to,
>
> [b] "我[小/中/大]学生時......" (Less common)

Singlish (Singaporean English):

> [a] "primary school that time..." or "that time primary school..." (More common)
>
> [b] "primary school student that time..." or "that time primary school student..." (Almost not used)

Arguably the [a] versions are not specific enough, because you can be referring to **any** time period that you were in (the) school, regardless of what role you are. I.e. you could be a student, teacher, staff, random civilian, etc. The [b] versions explicitly state that it's the time of being a student.

Also the Singlish versions (if anyone can understand it) show quite obviously why [a] is preferred to [b]. It's just a shorter sentence, and everything else is deduced from context. Being a native speaker of Singlish without any formal study into it I have no way to analyse it apart from just simply feeling that it's correct.

Comment: Thanks for the data to compare. When you have a full relative clause, saying that you are attending may be conceptually simpler than saying that you are a student there. So, what you show looks reasonable. But in the Japanese `...の` construction, I think it is natural to consider that the noun followed by `の` corresponds to a nominal predicate in a relative clause so that the relative clause is in the form `...<noun>だ`. In your English and Chinese expressions, the preferred forms are still full relative clauses because the predicate is not omitted (`was in`, `在`).

Comment: Looks like it's time to bring in Singlish (or Singaporean english).

Comment: Here in Beijing, we say "我上[小/中/大]学的时候.."

Comment: In fact, in Malay, the expression `masa sekolah rendah/menengah` (where `masa` is `時`) is valid and the most common. You can say it's a literal translation of the sentence in your question.